# Android :Capture media button action when Music player is Active

Tags: android, android-intent

I wrote some service which uses BroadcastReceiver to capture one of media buttons.I am able to capture the media button event only when Music player is Inactive. How can i capture media button event when my music player is active..!

MyActivity :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.about_and_activation_view);

Log.d("MR", "onCreate - " + getIntent().getAction());

    AudioManager mAudioManager  = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
      ComponentName mediaButtonReceiver = new ComponentName(getPackageName(), HeadsetControlEventReceiver.class.getName());
      mAudioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(mediaButtonReceiver);
}
```

MyBroadcastReceiver:

```
public class HeadsetControlEventReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try{
        KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);

        if ((event != null) && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK)) {
```

Manifest.Xml

```
  <receiver 
   android:name=".HeadsetControlEventReceiver" 
   android:enabled="true">
   <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON"/>
        </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

Comment: adding manifest changes,am not getting media_button event still when music player is active.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After you register this and music player is started the music player is given priority.Now some how you need to again re-register.How about a Cool Polling Mechanism.